# How to reach level 8 with larastan?

Tags: laravel, phpstan

I'm trying to have super clean **laravel** code using [larastan](https://phpstan.org/user-guide/rule-levels).

For the moment it is flawless up to level 7 (out of 9 possible). And I get stuck by going to 8 on this code:

```
$user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();

    if ($user) {
        $user = User::where('email', $request->email)->first();
        $user->tokens()->delete();
        $tokenResult = $user->createToken('authToken')->plainTextToken;
```

In this case, **$user** cannot be null. But larastan gives me this error:

```
Cannot call method tokens() on App\Models\User|null.
Cannot call method createToken() on App\Models\User|null.
```

What to do ? a particular annotation somewhere ?
Or maybe level 7 is already an excellent level and it's not worth going beyond?

Comment: Why are you reloading `$user`?

Comment: Thanks Mat, It was my mistake, so big that I couldn't see it. Now I am on level 8

Comment: Have you imported the traits